# Сортировка в python стандартной функцией sorted()

Tags: python, алгоритм

В python есть функция `sorted()`. Мне всегда было очень странно видеть, что эта функция реализована НЕ как чистая, т.е. она модифицирует то, что ей передаёшь в качестве аргументов. Это не самый хороший подход в программировании. Есть ли какие-нибудь за такую реализацию?

Comment: Есть, инплейс реализации меньше расходуют ресурсов. Если вопрос производительности у вас не стоит, можно использовать метод `sort`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Из-за того, что не происходит копирования и выделения памяти под новые объекты?

Comment: Да, из-за этого. При больших объёмах данных в сортируемой коллекции - это может быть чувствительно.

Comment: Извините, что вмешиваюсь, вы в этом диалоге не попутали sort и sorted между собой?